# DispatcherServlet sign outgoing response

Tags: spring, servlets

What would be the possible solution if I want to sign outgoing response, using Springs Dispatcher Servlet using MappingJacksonConverter.

My aim is to add md5 of body contents in header, to validate response.

By I cannot access headers after reading the response.

What are the suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for signing it the way you want is to do the following:

Create a servlet `Filter` that wraps the `HttpServletResponse` object in an implementation that writes to a temporary `ByteArrayOutputStream` and doesn't flush headers/content. When the `Filter` returns from `doFilter`, you get the [bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29) from the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, feed them to calculate the MD5 hash, add the response header, then flush the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own Mapping Conventer class. In my project, I use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with `jackson2` in classpath. I will give an example to show how to add header when convent response message.

First, extents `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` class

```
public class MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        outputMessage.getHeaders().add("code", DigestUtils.md5Hex(object.toString()));
        // add header before write body content
        super.writeInternal(object, outputMessage); // convent whatever you can

    }
}
```

Then add your own Conventer bean class to Spring-mvc config file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="com.xxx.utils.MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And this is the response headers for example above

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
code: 84fd2e9b2adc2f5be0b53a3ff7f1492b
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(7.6.8.v20121106)
```